# Creating a new SINGLES page presents a PAGE CAN'T BE FOUND or TEMPLATE CAN'T BE FOUND

Tags: templating, error-templates

I'm hoping you can help resolve my issue or point me in the right direction. Sincere apologies if this question has been asked a million times, however I can't seem to find anything specific to this issue.

I have been asked to create a new content page for a website that had already been built, I have never used Craft or Twig before. I read through the documentation and watched a few videos.

I created a new SINGLES as laid out in the documentation, an about us page had already been created which is very similar to the page I created, therefore I used this as a reference and all seems to be in order.

I created a new template again using the about us page and template for reference. When I view the new page in a browser I get a page can't be found and a template can't be found error.

Now, I didn't set this project up locally, I simply created the new template in a code editor, saved it and FTP'd it to the templates folder on the server.

I have read a right bit in an attempt to find the issue, to no avail. I renamed the about us Twig template out of curiosity and had expected a template can't be found error, however I didn't get an error, the about us page still works, which has confused me even more.

Would this be due to configuration? I have went through the code files checking the site is not set in development mode or set not to allow updates and everything seems to be in order.

So to summarise, I have absolutely no clue what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be several things, but perhaps most likely is that Craft isn't able to find the new single's entry template.

If you go into your new single's settings, in the "Site Settings" table you'll see a "Template" column. Assuming your single's entry template exists at `/templates/some-single.twig`, the value for the "Template" column should be `some-single` (or `some-single.twig`). If the template exists in a templates sub folder like `/templates/pages/some-single.twig`, the value should be `pages/some-single`.

Comment: Thanks, your feedback is greatly appreciated. I have figured out the issue and I don't even want to tell you what it was lol...

I will though as I am sure the suspense is killing you... Right, so the CMS details I was given were correct, however the FTP details they had given me were NOT for the live site. NEVER ASSUME, yea, well I did.

Again, thanks for taking the time to reply.